# save an array of data to one cell

Tags: c#

***I would like to save the array of `Days`to one cell, `TimeIn_AM`to one cell, `TimeOut_AM`to one cell, `TimeIn_PM`to one cell, and `TimeOut_PM` to one cell***

*Here is my Class and Save Method*

```
public class EmployeeSchedule
    {
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string RecordID { get; set; }
        public Schedule[] Schedule { get; set; }
    }
    public class Schedule
    {
        public string Days { get; set; }
        public string TimeIn_AM { get; set; }
        public string TimeOut_AM { get; set; }
        public string TimeIn_PM { get; set; }
        public string TimeOut_PM { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 for (int i = 0; i < employeeschedule.Schedule.Length; i++)
{
  SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("WorkSchedule_Save", MyConnection);
  mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.EmployeeID;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("@RecordID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = employeeschedule.RecordID;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Days", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].Days;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeIn_AM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeIn_AM;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeOut_AM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeOut_AM;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeIn_PM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeIn_PM;
  mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeOut_PM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeOut_PM;
}
```

**I want 1 `EmployeeID` and 1 `RecordID` for all of the array in the class `Schedule` but when i save it it creates a `EmployeeID` and `RecordID` for each data in the array.**

- And also if i move the `EmployeeID` and the `RecordID` from the loop it says `stored procedure or function [WorkSchedule_Save] has too many arguments`*

***Here is the data i want to save***

```
{
  "EmployeeID": "1000415",
  "RecordID": "1005",
  "Schedule": [
    {
      "Days": "Sunday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "",
      "TimeOut_AM": "",
      "TimeIn_PM": "",
      "TimeOut_PM": ""
    },
    {
      "Days": "Monday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "9:00",
      "TimeOut_AM": "12:00",
      "TimeIn_PM": "1:00",
      "TimeOut_PM": "5:00"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Tuesday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "9:00",
      "TimeOut_AM": "12:00",
      "TimeIn_PM": "1:00",
      "TimeOut_PM": "5:00"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Wednesday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "9:00",
      "TimeOut_AM": "12:00",
      "TimeIn_PM": "1:00",
      "TimeOut_PM": "5:00"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Thursday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "9:00",
      "TimeOut_AM": "12:00",
      "TimeIn_PM": "1:00",
      "TimeOut_PM": "5:00"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Friday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "9:00",
      "TimeOut_AM": "12:00",
      "TimeIn_PM": "1:00",
      "TimeOut_PM": "5:00"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Saturday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "",
      "TimeOut_AM": "",
      "TimeIn_PM": "",
      "TimeOut_PM": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The way you are storing the data is called FlatData, so if want to change it just store it into two tables which have a relationship with Id columns.

Comment: @AliKianoor is there any other way? like storing an array into one cell.

Comment: @sim what do you mean by cell ?

Comment: @Mohammed one cell in the data base

Comment: i want to save all the value of the array in one cell in the database

Comment: why not another linked table tho? @sim

Comment: @Mohammed how? i never done it before.. sorry im just a 2nd year student but i'm trying  to learn

Comment: yes, You can store it as a JSON string into one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSchedule]
(
    [EmployeeID ] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [RecordID ] INT NOT NULL
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]
(
    [Days] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [TimeIn_AM] NCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [TimeOut_AM] NCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [TimeIn_PM] NCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [TimeOut_PM] NCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [EmployeeId] INT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Schedule_ToEmployeeSchedule] FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [EmployeeSchedule]([EmployeeID]) 
)
```

I think it's better to change the classes to

```
public class EmployeeSchedule
    {
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string RecordID { get; set; }
        public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Schedule
    {
        public string Days { get; set; }
        public string TimeIn_AM { get; set; }
        public string TimeOut_AM { get; set; }
        public string TimeIn_PM { get; set; }
        public string TimeOut_PM { get; set; }
    }
```

and then when you save save to `EmployeeSchedule` and then save to `Schedule`

Answer (score 0):

You could but generally you don't do it this way in SQL.  (BTW this is a SQL & data modelling question, not C#).

You would have several tables along the lines of

```
 1. Employee
 2. Record
 3. ScheduleEntry
```

and save all the details in parts into those tables.  This option is really the only one that allows you to work usefully with the data using SQL.

A significantly worse option is to have one table with columns for each bit you anticipate

`EmployeeNumber, RecordID,   timeInMondayAM, timeOutMondayAM,timeInMondayPM, timeOutMondayPM, ... timeInAMSunday.. etc`.

Another option that I certainly wouldn't recommend is to have a schedule column of Text, JSON or XML for your array of values and store them there in an appropriate format.